# Javascript: named closure and memory management

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, closures

I'm trying to know more about memory management in JS and I have some question about closures.

Case **1**:

```
// Suppose that object var is capable to emit events 
var object = new EventEmitter();

object.addEventListener('custom-event', function callback(event) {
    object.removeEventListener('custom-event', callback);
    object = null;

    //Do some heavy computation like opening a specific view or somehthing similar
    var heavy_window = new HeavyWindow();
    heavy_window.open();
});
```

Case **2**:

```
// Suppose that object var is capable to emit events 
var object = new EventEmitter();

object.addEventListener('custom-event', callback = function(event) {
    object.removeEventListener('custom-event', callback);
    object = null;

    //Do some heavy computation like opening a specific view or somehthing similar
});
```

My questions are:

- Case 1:

  - Is correct to think that the `object` remains in memory until the `heavy_window` is not nulled?
  - Nulling the `object` var inside the closure can help gc?
- Case 2:

  - Naming a closure in this way `...addEventListener(callback = function() {})` instead of `...addEventListener(function callback() {})` can cause a memory leaks? Declaring `callback = function() {}` will cause a global hidden variable?

Note, I don't need examples in jQuery or using other framework. I'm interested to know more in JavaScript vanilla.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Regarding case 1, what do you think does `object` have to do with `heavy_window`?

Comment: @Bergi the `heavy_window` is created inside a listener attached to `object` so.. until the `heavy_window` exists the `object` remains in memory. Am I right?

Comment: No. The listener function might be attached to `object`, but the things created during the call are not. They go out of scope when the function returns, and nothing retains a reference to them. Unless you explicitly store them somewhere, or maybe `return` them from the function so that the caller might do anything with them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the details for garbage collecting is specified in the ES specification. However in most interpreters, objects will usually be garbage-collected once there doesn't exist any references to the object or not accessible, or scheduled at a later time.

In case 1, `heavy_window` might have access to the original `new EventEmitter` (`event` often has references to the event target) if you pass the event object into `HeavyWindow`, and thus your `new EventEmitter()` might not be garbage-collected until all references to your `heavy_window` are gone. If not, then your `new EventEmitter` will be garbage-collected at some point in the future.

In case 2, assigning the callback function to a global variable `callback` will not change anything because the callback function do not have any reference to the actual `new EventEmitter` object you have created. (Again, unless `event` has a reference to the `new EventEmitter` object you have created.)

In reality things might be a little different since garbage collectors in browsers are fairly complex. At what time the interpreter decides to collect the garbage is really up to it, but the bottom line is that it will only do it when all references to an object are gone.

Memory management usually isn't really a concern is JavaScript and you shouldn't need to be thinking about it most of the time. You will know it if there is a memory leak and able to detect it by using developer tools provided by the browser.